# In Azure DevOps is there a GUI way to disable tasks in YAML based pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Fairly new to Azure DevOps and using it for Infrastructure as Code Azure deployments.
Using Classic release pipelines, you can go into the pipeline, into a Stage and very quickly enable/disable tasks within that Stage

[image]

How would you do this with YAML pipelines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now with [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) you have a GUI option.
If you de-select the checkbox (see pic below) then you can pass that parameter to the pipeline.

[image]

There are [to my knowledge] three methods of implementing the runtime parameter in tasks and you can also apply most of logic in jobs/stages (with the exception that jobs/stages don't [currently] have an 'enabled' property);

```yaml
parameters:
- name: RunTask
  displayName: Run task?
  type: boolean
  default: true

steps:

- pwsh: Write-Host "always run this task"

- pwsh: Write-Host "skip this task when checkbox unticked..."
  condition: eq(${{ parameters.RunTask }}, true)

- pwsh: Write-Host "skip this task when checkbox unticked..."
  enabled: ${{ parameters.RunTask }}

- ${{ if eq(parameters.RunTask, true) }}:
  - pwsh: Write-Host "skip this task when checkbox unticked..."

- ${{ if parameters.RunTask }}:
  - pwsh: Write-Host "skip this task when checkbox unticked..."
```

Answer (score 30):

In addition to comment out tasks with `#`, here I provide another workaround :

You can try set variables : `enabled = false`, then use the variable in YAML file.

```
steps:
- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  enabled: false
  continueOnError: true
```

If set this way, this task will not run in the job.

[image]

This method is mentioned in this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/393253/add-support-to-temporarily-disableskip-a-job-in-mu.html), you can refer to it for details.

Comment: Template step does not seem to support `enabled` variable. So if you have a template as a step instead of a task, is there any other neat way to skip running it instead of commenting the whole block out?

Comment: @Yuhis, couldn't you just pass the enabled value into the template as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that from GUI really. well, you can, you just comment them out with `#`. in the editor

Comment: I thought that might be the case,  not as easy as using the gui for releases,  but you do have the pipeline as code...a trade off i guess.  Thanks